# Add and update with sqlalchemy in single commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, falconframework

I am new in sqlalchemy. I want to do add and update in single transaction for same model.code snippet is below. Application throwing error like **'Session' object has no attribute 'update'**

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
try:
    session = Session()
    user = UserProvision()
    user.username = admin["username"]
    user.password= admin["password"]
    user.client_id= admin["client_id"]
    user.fname= admin["fname"]
    user.lname= admin['lname']
    user.phone= admin['phone']
    session.add(user)
    session.flush()
    user_id = user.user_id
    user.name = admin["fname"]+" "+admin["lname"]
    user.setCreated_by=user_id
    user.setModified_by=user_id
    user.setCreated_name=admin["fname"]+" "+admin["lname"]
    user.setModified_name=admin["fname"]+" "+admin["lname"]
    user.setLast_reset_date=current_date
    user.setLast_reset_by = current_date
    session.update(user)
    session.flush()
    session.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print ex.__str__()
finally:
    session.close()
```

Comment: if its duplicate question, kindly provide link. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've added the model object to the session its state is already tracked for changes. There's no need to explicitly mark it as updated, and as you've noted there is no such method `Session.update()`. Simply remove that line and your code should work as expected.

The tracking is achieved through [instrumentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-instrumentation) of model class attributes:

> The SQLAlchemy [mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-mapping) process, among other things, adds database-enabled [descriptors](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-descriptors) to a mapped class which each represent a particular database column or relationship to a related class.

In other words when your model class is constructed the `Column` attributes will be replaced with [`InstrumentedAttribute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute) descriptor instances that among other things keep track of changes to the value.

Note that there's no need to manually flush just before [`Session.commit()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit):

> Flush pending changes and commit the current transaction.